# Binary Search in processing, ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: search, binary, processing

Basically, for revision purposes tried to code a Binary Search algorithm in Processing. Decided to use Processing for convenience. Can anybody spot the error because its baffling me. Thanks :)

```java
//Set size and font information.
size(400, 200);
background(0,0,0);
PFont font;
font = loadFont("Arial-Black-14.vlw"); 
textFont(font);

//Initialise the variables.
int[] intArray = new int[10];
int lower = 1;
int upper = 10;
int flag = 0;
int criteria = 10;
int element = 0;

//Populate the Array.
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  intArray[i] = i;
}

//Tell the user Array is filled.
text("Array Filled", 15, 20);

// Main loop.
while(flag == 0)
{
  //Sets the element to search by finding mid point.
  element = ((lower+upper)/2);

  //Checks if the mid point is equal to search criteria.
  if(intArray[element] == criteria)
  {
    flag = 1;
  }
  //Checks if the criteria is grater than the currently searched element.
  else if(criteria > intArray[element])
  {
    lower = (element+1);
  }
  else
  {
    upper = (element-1);
  }

  //Checks if the lower value is higher than the upper value.
  if(lower > upper)
  {
    flag = 2;
  }
}

//If no match is found.
if(flag == 2)
{
  text("Did not find criteria "+criteria, 15, 40); 
}
//If a match is found.
else
{
  text("Found "+criteria+" at index "+element+"", 15, 60); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize lower and upper, you set the values to 1 and 10, which is wrong. 1 and 10 would be the lowest and highest elements only if the array was 1-based (i.e. the first element is 1), but it's not, it's 0-based. Set the values to 0 and 9 and it should work.

Comment: Also, you're searching for 10, but ten isn't in the array, 0 through 9 are. The code should still work, it'll just return that it didn't find the element.

Comment: No worries! Easy mistake to make :)